# Delete one row from same rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table T with (first, second) columns. I have two rows with first=1 and second=2. I would like to delete just one of the rows. How do I do that?

Comment: Please specify the version of SQL Server you're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM YourTable 
WHERE first=1 and second=2
)
DELETE FROM CTE;
```

Or if SQL Server 2000

```
DELETE T
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM YourTable 
    WHERE [first]=1 and [second]=2
) T;
```

Then add a primary key.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ROW_NUMBER().

```
DECLARE @T as Table(First int , Second int )

INsert Into @T
Values (1,2),
(1,2)

SELECT * FROM @T

;WITH CTE as 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (order by first,second) rn , * from @T)

DELETE FROM CTE where rn = 1

select * from @T
```

If you change rn to include Partition by

`ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY first, second order by first,second)`

and change the where to be `WHERE RN <> 1`

you could use this as a general solution to remove any dupes on First, Second

Comment: Sadly, at the last gig we had a whole series of tables that were defined without a PK, and could not be corrected, so I had to create views that defined a "unique" value via row_number much like this answer proposes. Ugly, hacktastic but it works.

Comment: @EJC. No big deal. You did the right thing by deleting your answer.  I've got plenty of similarly deleted answers my self